# How to waite for the user input while executing the program using 'argparse' in python

Tags: python, multithreading, command-line-arguments, python-multithreading, argparse

I hope to run my program using multiple threads. One of them needs to waite for any input in order to excute corresping functions and stop the program. I want to use argparse to achieve that. However, it works really confusing:

```py
import threading, argparse
stop = False
lock = threading.Lock()

def pt():
    seq = 0
    while not stop:
        time.sleep(1)
        seq += 1
    print('pt stopping...')

def get_args():
    global stop
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('kill', action='store_true')
    start = time.time()
    while not stop:
        argv = input()
        try:
            args = parser.parse_args(argv)
        except:
            continue
        if args.kill:
            lock.acquire()
            try:
                stop = True
            finally:
                lock.release()
    print('get_args stopping...')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    g = threading.Thread(target=get_args, name='g')
    t = threading.Thread(target=pt, name='t')
    g.start()
    t.start()
    g.join()
    t.join()
    print('all stopped')
```

It can not recognize input properly. And whenever I push 'enter', it triggers stop signal.
The excuting result details are in the following image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNcTi.png)

Comment: `args = parser.parse_args()` is the normal way of using `argparse`.  But this reads the strings present in `sys.argv`, which it created by the calling script and the python interpreter.  In other words, when the code is called as a script.  It isn't intended for interactive use.  It may be possible to pass such arguments in multiprocessing.

Comment: Oh I see... but is it possible to build an interactive function using argparse? And how to achieve that? Thanks a lot!

Comment: `args=parser.parse_args(argv)` can be used, where `argv` is a list of strings that imitates what you'd get via `sys.argv`.